# Read secrets in Springboot deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have secrets configured in config/yaml file. There is one secret value that is causing trouble. I just want to print out the value being injected:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: myapplication-config
data:
  config.yaml: |
    'mysecret1': ${DB_PASSWORD}
    'mysecret2': ${ANOTHER_SECRET}
```

I make a GET request to the controller to print out the secret:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

@GetMapping("/test")
public String print(){
  System.out.println(env.getProperty("mysecret2"));
}
```

When I print it, it throws an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mysecret2' in value "${mysecret2}"
> at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)

Any idea how I can check the secrets sent to the application from config/env/dev/config.yaml?

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly. Do you want to retrieve the secret or you want to check it from the inside of your application?

Comment: @aurelius I think I didn't test enough. Anyway, it seems I can read them inside the application. I just wanted to see what values are being passed from docker or kubernetes. I wanted to see those values inside my application. Now I can do that fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to read them thru environment variable:

```
@Autowired 
private org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

//inside some method
@GetMapping("/test")
public String print(){
  System.out.println(env.getProperty("mysecret2"));
}
```

I tried using below but that didn't work.

```
@Value("${mysecret2})
private String mySecret2; //didn't work

....

System.getEnv("mySecret2"); //didn't work
System.getProperty("mySecret2"); //didn't work
```

Comment: ok, how would you get this value on the yaml / properties file ?   in my case i need the kubernetes secrets to connect on DB by spring boot JPA !!!

Comment: I didn't understand the question @TiagoMedici

Comment: So , i have the secrets created on kubernetes , and it is exposed as env vars , in my case i m trying to use it for jpa connect mysql, once i try to use on yaml file ${secret_pass} if failures !! here is the repo  https://github.com/jamesmedice/Spring-Boot-GCP

Comment: @TiagoMedici what are the keys? Lets take this example. The key is secret_pass. So you would pass them however you like, but in application, you can read them thru many ways: 1) @Value("${secret_pass}") private String secretPass; 2) Using the approach I mentioned in the answer. 3) in application.yml, using ${secret_pass} (just like how you mentioned.) I don't understand where is the disconnect. Can you check if your application is even receiving these env variables?

Comment: I just know couple of ways of passing these env/system variables. like this: 1) java -jar yourapplication.jar -Dsecret_pass="1234"  or 2)  java -jar yourapplication.jar --secret_pass="1234"  . Both of these approaches work. However, I don't know how to set them in kubernetes.

Comment: the point is how to use that on kubernetes .. there is something missing under config / cloud , once i try to use the dependency :spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config, i got an exception java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to kubernetes.docker.internal/127.0.0.1:6443

Comment: sorry @TiagoMedici, Kubernetes is beyond my understanding at this point. What I was doing was the reading part. Setting part, I haven't encountered it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier way to read the environment variable from the Kubernetes secret is using `@Value` in Spring Boot

```
@GetMapping("")
public String alive(@Value("${ENCOURAGE_PASSWORD:default-secret}") String passwordFromSecret, @RequestParam(value = "password", defaultValue = "default-input") String passwordFromUser) {
    if(passwordFromSecret.equals(passwordFromUser)) {
        return greeting + " dear user. Thank you Jesus for I am alive, yay!" + " but now I am busy learning, so " + farewell;
    } else {
        return "No entry - you did not provide the password! You provided: " + passwordFromUser + " Next time :) say: " + passwordFromSecret;
    }
}
```

Here is how you would set the password ("open") in a secret and pass on to Kubernetes

```
$kubectl create secret generic PASSWORD --from-literal=password=open --prefix=ENCOURAGE_

$ k edit deployments.apps regular-encourager

        - name: ENCOURAGE_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: PASSWORD
              name: regenc-secret
              
$ k get secrets regenc-secret -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  PASSWORD: b3Blbg==
kind: Secret              

$ kubectl set env --from=secret/regenc-secret --prefix=ENCOURAGE_ deployment/regular-encourager

$ echo b3Blbg== | base64 -d
$open
```

verify the value in the environment in k8s by opening a shell

```
$ k exec -it regular-encourager-cfbc859c5-nbb6w -- bash
root@regular-encourager-cfbc859c5-nbb6w:/app# env
FAREWELL_FROM_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=Bon Voyage
ENCOURAGE_PASSWORD=open
```

now test it

```
# curl  http://localhost:8080/?password=ope

No entry - you did not provide the password! You provided: ope Next time :) say :open

root@regular-encourager-cfbc859c5-nbb6w:/app# curl  http://localhost:8080/?password=open
HOLA! dear user. Thank you Jesus for I am alive, yay! but now I am busy learning, so Bon Voyage
root@regular-encourager-cfbc859c5-nbb6w:/app#
```